# reading from file from different lines, creating new objects

Tags: c++

I have the following class :

```
class Player {
string m_name;
int m_age;
string m_team;
string m_position;
double m_speed;
```

I'm using this function to save every one of the class members to a new line in a .txt file

```
void save (){
    ofstream ofS ("Players.txt", ios::app);
    ofS<<m_name<<endl;
    ofS<<m_age<<endl;
    ofS<<m_team<<endl;
    ofS<<m_position<<endl;
    ofS<<m_speed<<endl;
    }
```

And this function to create a vector of pointers to players from the txt file:

```
static /*vector<Player*>*/ void load(){
    ifstream ifS ("Players.txt");
    vector<Player*> players;
    string buffer1;
    while (ifS){
            Player* temp = new Player;
            getline (ifS, temp->m_name);
            ifS>>temp->m_age;
            getline (ifS, buffer1);
            getline (ifS, temp->m_team);
            getline (ifS, temp->m_position);
            ifS>>temp->m_speed;
            players.push_back(temp);
        }

    cout<<players.size()<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i < players.size(); i++){
        cout<<"The "<<i+1<<" player is "<<players[i]->m_name<<" "<<players[i]->m_age<<" "<<players[i]->m_team<<" "<<players[i]->m_position<<" "<<players[i]->m_speed<<endl;
    }

    }
```

However my program seems to only read the first player in the .txt file - the first 5 lines of the file. This makes me believe the line

```
while (ifS)
```

causes all my problems. I tried replacing it with

```
while (ifS.eof() != true)
```

or

```
while (getline(ifS, buffer2))
```

but none of them created the expected result. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, my question was answered by the proposed duplicate question. Thank you very much! Also, I'm sorry for the duplicate, but I really didn't know the same reason behind the other question's problem was responsible for mine.